# image quality goes off when GETIMAGE is used in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

In my GUI I've so many operations to perform on image. Including `crop`,`flip`,`resize` etc., below code shows some of such functions. In my opening function i took the image from previous window

```
function Pre_processing_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;
fname = getappdata(0, 'fname');
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(fname);
[path,name,ext,ver] = fileparts(fname);
handles.fname = strcat(name,ext);
[handles.queryx, handles.querymap] = imread(fname);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

For flip

```
function Flip_H_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
a = getimage(handles.axes1);
hflip = flipdim(a,2);
axes(handles.axes1);
    imshow(hflip);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

For rotate

```
function rotate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
a = getimage(handles.axes1);
Ra = get(handles.angle, 'string');
Na = str2num(Ra);
rotate = imrotate(a,Na);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(rotate);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I've shown only 2 functions, but so many similar functions are there in my GUI.
Figure shown below is original image
[image: Original]

The moment i press `flip` then image quality goes off as shown below
[image: Edited image]

Images I'm using are of 8 bit depth and `BMP` format.

Comment: I would not rely on storing/saving/getting your image in an `axes`. Why not having two external variables containing (1) your original image and (2) the actual image - much easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what are two external variables

Comment: I could have been more explicit! In your code, the `axes` you display your image in plays an additional role: _store_ a resulting image after an operation, and _retreive_ the image for an additional operation. This  makes it hard to find out what is going wrong in your code (gui? flip? getimage?). You may use two variable to store your image in (input image and resulting image) , and use the `axes` only for display (so `getimage` will not be used anymore). You will be able to tell if `flip` or `gui` is responsible for the bad results.

Comment: Its not only the `flip` operation, but all other operations which you can see in figure results in same type of image (like in second figure). Before using `getimage` i had this problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064669/updating-data-within-same-gui-in-matlab]